# IEquatable<'1> on interface

Tags: c#, interface, equality, iequatable

So, I've got a interface for entities that requires them to expose their *identity*.

```
public interface IEntity<TIdentity> {
    public TIdentity Id { get; } 
}
```

Now I need to be able to compare two entities which each other, but I can't rely on the default implementations of `Equals` and `GetHashCode` because entities should be compared by their *identity*, and not overall signature. Since every class that implements `IEntity<'1>` should be comparable, I thought about declaring `IEquatable<'1>` directly on the entity interface.

Well.. that doesn't work. When I declare `IEquatable<'1>` on `IEntity<'1>` the interface enforces implementing classes to implement the following:

```
public bool Equals(IEntity<'1> other)
```

instead of

```
public bool Equals(TypeImplementingIEntity other)
```

So upon calling `Equals` on two entities, the runtime refers back to `Equals(object obj)` because the  type of the argument on the method provided by `IEquatable<'1>` does not match the actual type! What do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work. `Equals(IEntity<TIdentity>)` should take precedence over `Equals(object)`

You should override `Equals(object)` anyway:

```
public override bool Equals(object other) {
    return Equals(other as IEntity<TIdentity>);
}
```

Comment: According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371328/why-is-it-important-to-override-gethashcode-when-equals-method-is-overridden) it is important to override `GetHashCode()` too.

Comment: Yes you should, but that's not what this question was about, so I didn't mention it.